# hide one element on my webpage when the user will print it

Tags: asp.net, css

the template of my website looks quite good when printed, so i have no separate print css.

However, there is one element at the top which is not needed when printed, and about 2 inches high, so that's kind of a waste at the top of the printed page (which imho distracts the user from the actual content)

So, what i want to accomplish, is 'hide' that element (div) at the top of the page when a user prints the page.

But so far the only solution i've seen is top create a separate css document which then will be used when the user will print my page. That sounds good, but do i now have to maintain 2 different stylesheets with exact the same content (besides that one div)?

Or is it possible to sort of override the standard stylesheet in the print stylesheet? (so i only have to define the exception for that one div in my print stylesheet?)

Hope this explains my problem.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare your main stylesheet to apply to *all* media ([browsers apply it to all by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921573/is-there-no-difference-between-no-media-and-media-all-in-css-link/6921600#6921600)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
```

Then adding a print stylesheet should not require you to duplicate styles across both CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

All you would do is add the print-specific styles to `print.css`.

But if you want to keep a single stylesheet, and have print-specific overrides within that one stylesheet, you can place the rules in a print media rule:

```
@media print {
    div.do-not-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you asked vor: [overriding the standard css in your print style](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml)