# Is there no difference between No media and media="all" in css link?

Tags: html, css

Is there no difference between No media and media="all"?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Netscape 4 didn't recognize media types, so adding `media="all"` let the browser ignore and therefore hid the stylesheet from Netscape 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[In HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#adef-media), the default value is `screen`.
[In HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#attr-link-media), the default value has been changed to `all`.

<del>Therefore, it depends on the doctype declaration you use in your page.</del> Never mind, user agents get confused about standards anyway; see Knu's comment. (I bet this is why they changed it to `all` in HTML5.)

Then again, this only really matters if you're supporting user agents that don't present pages on digital screens, or display any visual information for that matter.

Comment: What will happen if I'm using HTML5 Doctype but user is on IE 6/7? Browser will take the default as `all` or `screen`

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Why does it matter? IE6 and IE7 are both `screen` media anyway, so either `screen` or `all` would work. My best guess is `screen`.

Comment: Because if we are using projector with IE6/7 to show explain some hacks and quirks

Comment: OK. You mean we don't need media="projection" in that case for IE.

Comment: [If it’s omitted, this attribute defaults to media="screen", according to the HTML4 specification, but in reality, browsers seem to apply media="all" if the attribute is omitted.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/linkingcss)

Comment: @Knu - Is it for all browsers of specific?

Comment: @Vyas you would have to test yourself but HTML(5) has a habit of standardizing the de facto implementation of the browsers. And SitePoint is an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 5):

Both yes and no it seems. In section [14.4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.4.1) in the specs it says that a stylesheet without a media-type applies to all medias, whilst the other are filtered out when not needed. 
But in section [14.2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#adef-media) it should default to screen, which should be used on non-paged computer screens whilst all should be suitable for all devices ([more information on media-descriptors here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-media-descriptors)).

Comment: Maybe it's only the case when a LINK with `media="screen"` has been included before. Effectively becoming a default cascade (screen > all).

Answer (score 1):

Media refers to at which the css file applicable eg: screen, print etc.. 
Default is all. 
Means if you don't specify any media the parser take it as all

[Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Answer (score 0):

**I would never use "all" in externally linked style sheets.** The reality is browsers the past 20 years have not always followed recommendations. You still have too much confusion, as well as partial browser support, using "all":

1. "all" was not supported in older browsers like the Netscape 4 series
2. IE6 had issues using "screen" for media type, and relied on "all", while many others would not support it back then.
3. Many browsers defaulted to "all" when the media attribute was excluded back then, even if "screen" was supposed to be the default.
4. When using "all" in @import style sheet calls, IE 4-7 will fail to load the style sheet.
5. Support of "all" in media queries is also partially supported compared to "screen".
6. "All" comes with its own bugs and quirks...like the fact it could mess up "print" sheets added later, and some browsers failed to import styles when printing using "all".
7. In the past, 'link' tags without a "media" and "title" attribute not only defaulted to "all" media types in some older browsers, but meant your linked style sheet were seen by all media devices as optional or `"preferred"` sheets a user could change in their browser.

All reasons not to ever use "media=all" in linked style sheets. My recommendation is to always use EXPLICIT media types like "screen" or "print". But if your only option is to design a sheet for any and all possible devices, you can remove the "media" attribute when needing to simulate "all". Just understand the problems listed above.