# Media=All vs Media=Screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

It seems like recently I have seen many more people starting to use `media="all"` vs `media="screen"` in their stylesheets.

My question is when should I use `media="all"` over `media="screen"` and vice versa?

Note: I am using HTML5 Doctype if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
media="all"    // Used for all media type devices ( its default under html 5)
media="screen" // Used for computer screens(default value  for html 4.01)
```

**Good read**

[7.3 Recognized media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) 
[Is there no difference between No media and media=“all” in css link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921573/is-there-no-difference-between-no-media-and-media-all-in-css-link)

Comment: The default value used to be `screen` in previous HTML specs, and was only changed to `all` in HTML5. In spite of this, browsers have always treated it as `all`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921573/is-there-no-difference-between-no-media-and-media-all-in-css-link/6921600#6921600

Comment: @BoltClock, and OP uses HTML5

Comment: @BoltClock you are quite correct its quite confusing i should have been show it

Answer (score 3):

According to [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html):

> ##### 7.3 Recognized media types
>
> The names chosen for CSS media types reflect target devices for
> which the relevant properties make sense. In the following list of CSS
> media types the names of media types are normative, but the
> descriptions are informative. Likewise, the "Media" field in the 
> description of each property is informative.
>
> **all**
>
> Suitable for all devices.
>
> **braille**
>
> Intended for braille tactile feedback devices.
>
> **embossed**
>
> Intended for paged braille printers.
>
> **handheld**
>
> Intended for handheld devices (typically small
> screen, limited bandwidth).
>
> **print**
>
> Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on
> screen in print preview mode.  Please consult the section on paged media for information about formatting
> issues that are specific to paged media.
>
> **projection**
>
> Intended for projected presentations, for example projectors.
> Please consult the section on paged media for
> information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.
>
> **screen**
>
> Intended primarily for color computer screens.
>
> **speech**
>
> Intended for speech synthesizers. Note: CSS2 had a similar media type 
> called 'aural' for this purpose.  See the appendix on 
> aural style sheets for details.
>
> **tty**
>
> Intended for media using a fixed-pitch character grid (such as
> teletypes, terminals, or portable devices with limited display
> capabilities). Authors should not use pixel units with the "tty" media
> type.
>
> **tv**
>
> Intended for television-type devices (low 
> resolution, color, limited-scrollability screens, sound available).

Comment: A lot of these are depreciated and shouldn't be used. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_types): "Deprecated media types: CSS2.1 and Media Queries 3 defined several additional media types (tty, tv, projection, handheld, braille, embossed, and aural), but they were deprecated in Media Queries 4 and shouldn't be used. The aural type has been replaced by speech, which is similar."