# How to determine if a device is in portrait or landscape mode using CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, landscape-portrait

For determining screen size I'm using `media queries` but I want determine if a device is in `portrait or landscape mode using CSS` so that I can have different background image as per screen size.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

simply write media queries for landscape and portrait modes:

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
/* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
/* Landscape styles */
}
```

[link here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/)

Comment: In HTML5 **media screen** becomes **media all**, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549267/media-all-vs-media-screen