# What is the benefit of using 'all' in a media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference between

```
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
     // some css
}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
     // some css
}
```

Quite often I see the first declaration, but is there any benefit of including `all`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549267/media-all-vs-media-screen

Comment: As far as I understand, browsers which support media queries apply the styling inside media query block no matter whether there is word 'all' specified or not. Old browsers skip the media query all together anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no benefit. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

> Unless you use the `not` or `only` operators, the media type is optional
>   and the `all` type will be implied.

The `all` type is implied, so `@media (min-width: 500px)` is interpreted as `@media all and (min-width: 500px)` and the two statements are equivalent. The latter is just needlessly specific.